# Openssl Decrypt in PHP without -iv -pass

Tags: php, macos, encryption, openssl

I want to decrypt an already encrypted text i have, i manage it to do it by command in MacOS Terminal.

```
printf "encrypted text" | openssl enc -d -base64 -A -aes-256-cbc -k "abcde" -nosalt
```

In MacOS Terminal it runs fine, i get the decrypted message, but i tried this in php and failed.

```
<?php

$method = 'aes-256-cbc';
$password = substr(hash('sha256', 'abcde', true), 0, 32);
$iv = chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0);
$decoded = openssl_decrypt(base64_decode($token), 'AES-256-CBC', $password, 0, $iv);
return $decoded;

?>
```

I don't know how terminal handles the -nosalt key to get iv and pass, i tried with empty iv and failed. What is the php equivalent code for this?

Comment: Uhh no idea, because when you fail to specify an IV to `openssl enc` it's derived from the key, which is a bad idea and I can't find the documentation for. Also not specifying a key derivation function defaults to something insecure which I also can't find the documentation for, and lastly the `-nosalt` option _is_ documented, but with `This option SHOULD NOT be used except for test purposes or compatibility with ancient versions of OpenSSL.`. So uhhh... don't do anyt of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Let's start with a serious warning (that was commented by @Sammitch as well): Please do not use this function in production as it UNSECURE.** Kindly use it only for migration to a much better key derivation.

To your question: OpenSSL uses an **outdated** key derivation to generate the key and the necessary initialization vector (IV). You could find a lot of examples here on SO to see how the key derivation works and how you could use it programmatically in PHP.

I will show you a way how to do it with OpenSSL for a single task. You ran the encryption this way:

```
printf "encrypted text" | openssl enc -d -base64 -A -aes-256-cbc -k "abcde" -nosalt
```

and receive the decrypted text. Your passphrase in use is "abcde". When adding an additional parameter "-P" you will be shown the derivated key and IV, in your case this values (all values in hex notation):

```
printf "encrypted text" | openssl enc -d -base64 -A -P -aes-256-cbc -k "abcde" -nosalt   
key=36BBE50ED96841D10443BCB670D6554F0A34B761BE67EC9C4A8AD2C0C44CA42C
iv =2A34E82FFC2B85AA708049C7CD64A6A1
```

Now you can use these values in PHP for decryption (use hex2bin for conversion).

Btw.: the parameter "-P" just shows the key and IV without decryption, using "-p" shows the key and IV and runs the decryption.

Comment: I actually tried this before and didn't work for me, i have no idea why i tried to recreate it now and it actually worked, i guess i did something wrong before. This is all just for testing purposes but i'm glad your answer worked for me. Using the -P command to get the derivated key and IV to use in PHP worked.

Comment: I'm glad I could help you, could you kindly mark my answer as "accepted" ?